# Mimekit how to embed svg without attach them

Tags: c#, .net, svg, mailkit, mimekit

I have this little piece of code

```
var builder = new BodyBuilder();
var image = builder.LinkedResources.Add(logoPath);
image.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
textMsg = textMsg.Replace("{logo}", image.ContentId);
builder.HtmlBody = textMsg;
msg.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

It works perfectly except that if I use a .png image it isn't attach to the mail but if it is an .svg it is attach. I tried to convert the svg to base64 but it didn't work.

As I show in the images below, if it is a .svg the image is attach at the top of the mail but if it is a.png it doesn't.  Is it possible to do the same with .svg? I don't want the attached file.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is a limitation of the receiving mail client, not anything you are doing wrong with the images in your email message.

The client you are using to receive the message does not support SVG and so has decided that whenever it encounters an SVG image, it will offer it to the user as an attachment.